# Code-based transclude inside an each doesn't work for the final element

Tags: angularjs

In [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MrzYkacqfdFsEd85PAEa) I have a transcluded directive inside of an `ng-each`. It seems to only include the transclusion on the last pass through the each!

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.directive ('labeledElement', [
() => {
 const link = ($scope, $el, attrs, _0, transclude) => {
  $scope.label = attrs.label;
  $el.find('label').prepend(transclude());
 }
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  link,
  scope: {
   label: '@',
  },
  transclude: true,
  template: `
<label>
 <span class="label">{{label}}</span>
</label>
`,
 }
}])

app
.controller('TopLevel',
 function() {
  this.sources = [
   { domain:"first item"},
   { domain:"second item"},
   { domain:"third item"},
  ]
 })

angular.bootstrap (document.querySelector('body'), ['testApp'])
```

```html
<body ng-controller="TopLevel as $ctrl">
    <style>
      input:invalid+.label {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  <p>Why on earth does only the last input display?</p>
 <section class="admin-integration-sources">
  <div>
   <ul class="configured-sources-list">
    <li ng-repeat="source in $ctrl.sources">
     <labeled-element label="A Label">
      <input ng-model="source.domain" required />
     </labeled-element>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
```

A few things to note

- If I were to use `<ng-transclude>` in the template itself things work *but* the creation of an intermediate `<ng-transclude>` element breaks the css pattern of `input:invalid+.label` which I consider foundational to how both my app *and* html is meant to work.
- `ng-transclude` as an attribute works as well but will wipe out my `span.label`
- This definitely has something to do with `ng-each`. If I create three `li` elements manually and link them to `$ctrl.sources[0]`, `$ctrl.sources[1]`, etc it works just fine!

What is going on!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transclusion wasn't designed to work this way.  You have two transclusions happening at the same scope, <li> and <labeled-element>, which is the scope of <body>.

Essentially each iteration of ng-repeat is stomping on the prior <labeled-element> transclusion, which is why only the last <labeled-element> transclusion appears.

[Here's an expert explanation of the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7842).

The solution is to use compile to fix up the markup as you need it.

```
app.directive('labeledElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        compile: function (element, attr) {
            let template = angular.element('<label><span class="label">' + element.attr('label') + '</span></label>');
            // Extract the children from this instance of the directive
            let children = element.contents();
            // Wrap the children in our template
            let injectElement = template.find('inject');
            injectElement.replaceWith(children);
            // Append this new template to our compile element
            element.append(template);
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bn4YiPKmhrhUYTugQJ8C?p=preview) reproducing your issue and workaround using **compile**.

Comment: Dear god that's terrible...Now we have to manually handle updates of every piece of information (and what even happens when the contents change) That is shockingly worthless. They're in effect saying that you should never use transclude since if you create a reusable component you can't control whether it will ever be used inside of an `ng-each` or not!

Comment: Also what I don't understand - why does the bug only manifest when you do `transclude()` in the linking function and not when you transclude in the markup.

Comment: Here's a good article about the workings of ng-repeat fwiw http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/